# Is there any way to get DirectX on a server?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, gpu, emulation, rendering

I'm trying to get DirectX 6 (or newer, or OpenGL instead) to work on a VMware virtual machine (server). I can't enable 3D acceleration, I only have Admin access to the machine. The app I'm trying to run can't run without these (there are only simple graphics). Is there any way of getting some software to render with the CPU and emulate graphics functionality instead?

Edit: It's Windows; I can get pretty much any recent version (XP, Server 2003 or 2007, 7).

Comment: What does the OS are you running on the VM exactly? And what software are you trying to run?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the issue is the lack of 3d hardware - there's actually ways around that, developed for use in systems with less powerful graphics cards.

Depending on the application [3d analyse](http://www.tommti-systems.com/main-Dateien/files.html) might work. There also used to be an emulator called swiftshader that you'd replaced your d3d dll with to do the same thing -transgaming bought it, but [there seems to be a demo version](http://transgaming.com/swiftshader) (and [chrome seems to use it](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/02/gpu-accelerating-2d-canvas-and-enabling.html)  .  You'll have to test these to see if it works acceptably for your needs.

Comment: No luck with these :( the app still won't work.